# Backbone render setTimeOut

Tags: backbone.js

I have a strange problem into my app.
When I render a collection it was "empty" if I print it but when I console.log this collection inside collection there is twho arrays inside models.
Well this is my script:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore', 
    'backbone', 
    'text!templates/folder.html',
    'models/folder',
    'collections/folder',
    ], function($, _, Backbone, FolderTemplate, FolderModel, FolderCollection){
    var FolderView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#folder'),
        template:_.template(FolderTemplate),

        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log(this.collection.models);
        }
    });

    return FolderView;
});
```

to call the view I use it inside another app:

```
this.folders = new FolderCollection();
this.folders.fetch({ data: { dir: 'uploads'} });
this.foldersView = new FolderView({collection: this.folders});
```

With this app `console.log(this.collection.models);` is empty
But if I make something like this with a setTimeOut it works the console.log return me the right arrays:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore', 
    'backbone', 
    'text!templates/folder.html',
    'models/folder',
    'collections/folder',
    ], function($, _, Backbone, FolderTemplate, FolderModel, FolderCollection){
    var FolderView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#folder'),
        template:_.template(FolderTemplate),

        initialize: function(){
            var here = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                  here.render();
            },800);
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log(this.collection.models);
        }
    });

    return FolderView;
});
```

How can I use `this.render()` without a setTimeOut, because I think isn't correct or not logic to make something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
initialize: function(){
  var self = this;
  this.collection.fetch({
     success: function(){
         self.render();
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the `reset` event which will invoke the `render` method

Replace

```
initialize: function(){
   var here = this;
   setTimeout(function(){
   here.render();
   },800);
},
```

with

```
initialize: function(){
   this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
},
```

Comment: I think events are an elegant way of dealing with asynchronous code, but you should make sure that the collection actually triggers the `reset` event: `this.collection.fetch({ reset: true })` and that the event callback is registered **before** it actually happens. That means that the `fetch` should happen when the view is getting instantiated, not before.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having to do this is because `this.folders.fetch` takes time. Instead of setting a timeout you should be using [events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) instead. [`Collection.fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) will fire a `change` event on success.

So, instead consider something like:

```
this.collection.on("change", this.render);
```

Comment: It definitely does, see [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). Alternatively, you can override the `success` method in the `Collection.fetch` options parameter

Comment: Well, I don't understand why it doesn't work, I have put the "listener" inside the initialize of my App, is correct?

Comment: @juco, your partially right. `fetch` will only fire a change event for existing models that have been changed.

Comment: I think the problem is because change doesn't fire the first set of the collection right? @fbynite